# How to square all the number in my array? Golang

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var square int
    box := [4]int{1, -2, 3, 4}

    square = box * *box

    fmt.Println("The square of the first box is", square)
}
```

Anyone can tell me the correct way to square it?
The problem is invalid direct of square(type[4]int)

Comment: What is `**` supposed to do?

Comment: `**` isn't an operator, so you have `box * (*box)`, but `box` isn't a pointer so you can't de-reference it. (it still wouldn't make sense if it was a pointer either)

Comment: @FUZxxl i actually want to square it, sorry for my mistake

Comment: thx for correct me @plusmid
im a beginner,can you suggest me any ebook or reference of golang?

Comment: @AnthonyFSS: Take a look at ['go' tag wiki - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info).

Comment: @AnthonyFSS There is the [Go specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  box := []int{1, -2, 3, 4}
  square := make([]int, len(box))
  for i, v := range box {
    square[i] = v*v
  }

  fmt.Println("The square of the first box is ", square)
}
```